# Adding Roles with Rules upon Webform submission not working — Why?

Tags: webforms, rules, users

Here's what I have done so far (in Drupal 7):

1. Created a webform quiz that only validates if all answers are correct
2. Created a role called "Mid-program quiz: Passed" that has permissions to view a particular page
3. Created a rule that says upon submission of the quiz, the submitting user should be granted the "Mid-program quiz: Passed" role.

But it's not working. The quiz is being submitted correctly but the role is not being assigned.

Here are the details of the rule that's failing to execute:

---

## Event

Event: After a webform submission has been added

## Conditions: Webform has name

Parameter: The form id of the submitted form: [form_id], Webforms: Mid-program quiz

## Elements

(Here I wasn't sure whether to use [user], i.e. the user submitting the webform,  or [site:current-user], i.e. the currently logged-in user. So I did both.)

### Add user role

Parameter: User: [user], Roles: Mid-program quiz: Passed

### Add user role

Parameter: User: [site:current-user], Roles: Mid-program quiz: Passed

---

Can someone see where the problem is in this rule?

Thanks!

Comment: Upon further debugging, it also looks like the problem isn't with Event or the Elements. It appears to be in the Conditions. I also tried  
Webform has name
Parameter: The form id of the submitted form: [node:title], Webforms: Mid-program quiz
... but that doesn't work either.

Comment: You said it looks like the problem is in the conditions... so if you remove the condition, the role evaluates correctly?

Comment: Yes. Without the condition the role is added to the user upon submission of any webform. I actually figured out the problem and typed up an answer but I have to wait 8 hours from the original question before I can post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Adding Roles with Rules upon Webform submission not working — Why?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30508/answer/submit)

Okay, it looks like I figured it out:

---

- Event: After a webform has been submitted
- Condition: Webform has name

  - Parameters:

    - The form id of the submitted form: [form_id]
    - Webforms: Mid-program quiz

Action: Add user role

- Parameters:

  - User: [user]
  - Roles: Mid-program quiz: Passed

---

So the confusing things to watch out for are:

- "After a webform has been submitted" is the one to choose, over "After a webform submission has been added."
- Webform Has Name has first parameter as ID and second as the webform (as selected from a list of webforms). It makes it seem like you're saying nid has to be equal to a title, which doesn't seem like it would work, but that's apparently not what's happening.
- Add user role takes simply Parameter:user, rather than site:user or any other attribute of user